# Inconsistent rotations with \sidewaysfigure

Tags: floats, double-sided, rotating

In my document I'm largely using `\sidewaysfigure`. However, this results pictures with *inconsistent* placement and direction of included pictures and captions. By inconsistent I mean that figures and captions are not rotated to one side always (eg, to the right). EG, on page 1 the caption is on the left side, and on page 2 on the right side.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy pictures

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Bar}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I wonder if there is a simple option with `\sidewaysfigure` that would force the *whole thing* (pics and captions) to be rotated for 180 degrees.

Comment: Can you post your code that produces inconsistent rotation?

Comment: @HarishKumar Edited...

Comment: Please add complete code starting from `\documentclass{}` and ending at `\end{document}` so that others who try to help you need not type/guess the class and packages you are using.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "inconsistent", but have you read section 2.1 in [the manual for `rotating`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/rotating)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling the rotation direction of the sideways figure environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94578/controlling-the-rotation-direction-of-the-sideways-figure-environment)

Comment: @boy Whenever you’re posting code here, please make sure a) that you’ve removed _everything_ that’s not necessary to reproduce the problem (Your code contained 19 (!) packages that were entirely irrelevant) and b) that the problem is actually reflected in the code (Your code only produced one figure – how is that supposed to show inconsistency?). Please study the _Minimal Working Example_ I extracted from your code. Also, for issues like that, pictures of the output are enormously helpful. Please do these things yourself when you’re posting your next question.

Answer (score 20):

The behaviour is perfectly consistent, in that the caption is always rotated toward the outer edge of the page. This is default if the `twoside` argument is given to the documentclass, which is default for the `book` class.

To override this, add either `figuresleft` or `figuresleft` as an (optional) argument to the `rotating` package, i.e.

```
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
```

as described in the manual, section 2.1:

> If the `twoside`  option has been given to the main document class
>   (either explicitly, or implicitly as in the default for `book` class),
>   the package will rotate sideways figures according to the page number
>   (this requires at least two passes through LaTeX). If you want the
>   `twoside` option, but want the figures always in one direction, use
>   the `figuresright` or `figuresleft` options to the package.

Comment: this takes about 3000 times longer to compile, with the figuresleft or figures right option specified.

Comment: @ADP Really? Never used the package much, so I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 1):

With the `lscape` package you can simply rotate the entire page. The result is then very consistent and the PDF is readable without turning your head. The printer will know what to do with it as well.

```
\begin{landscape}
A landscape page with figures...
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my printer didn't ...