# Controlling the rotation direction of the sideways figure environment

Tags: floats, rotating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent rotations with \sidewaysfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93924/inconsistent-rotations-with-sidewaysfigure)

Using the sideways figure environment how can one control whether the rotation is clockwise or counter-clockwise?

I understand the default is clockwise on pages left of spine and counter-clockwise on pages right of spine, (so the caption is always facing out from the spine), This is logical for pictures / images, however, when plots are involved (with axes and labels), this can result in upside-down y-axis labels when the document is held in the natural position, as in the below sample, showing upside down Y-Axis Label.

[image: Output]

I personally think it is better to have the SAME rotation on every page, anyone with a different opinion?

Comment: my opinion: all landscape figures should have the same orientation, with the caption (assumed at the bottom) in the direction of reading progress; for english and other european languages, that's on the right.  that way, if figures are on facing pages, one has to turn the book sideways only once, and can look at both figures at the same time.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's my opinion too, the sideways environment behaves differently...

Comment: @barbarabeeton : I'd go further to specify a minor nit: that for LTR work, the tables should be rotated 90 degrees anticlockwise. In that way, the reader rotates the book clockwise, and the tables are in the correct order, with table 1 above table 2. (Obviously, the opposite for RTL work.)

Comment: Related: [Inconsistent rotations with \sidewaysfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93924/93941#93941)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - They address the same point, but this question is much clearer than that, so I recommend we close the older question as a duplicate of this one.  Also, the other question does not raise the issue of upside-down captions.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Cool. I solved this by using \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}. I do my plotting using knitr and R, fixing the upside-down cases was a bit more of a challenge... I ended up doing it by creating a chunk to specifically change the angle of text rotation prior to plotting, changing it back immediately after so any future plots on a portrait page wouldn't be affected. Its probably a bit of a hack, but I am pleased with the result.