# Change rotations with sidewaysfigure and twoside option

Tags: pdftex, rotating, double-sided

I am trying to rotate a figure using the `rotating` package (with the `sidewaysfigure` environment) in a document using the `twoside` option. By default, the `twoside` option will set uneven pages to be on the right, and even pages on the left. Now, the rotating package promises to take this to account, and actually does rotate figures clockwise or counterclockwise depending on the page number. However, it does the exact opposite of what I want; figures that are on uneven pages (i.e. on the right of a printed document) have their captions on the right, on the far side of the binding. I would like the caption to be on the side of the binding, is this possible? I have included a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image: result-of-MWE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent rotations with \sidewaysfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93924/inconsistent-rotations-with-sidewaysfigure)

Comment: I have seen that post, but what that person wants is to have the same rotations throughout the document despite the `twoside` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there does not seem to be a build in option for this, you could try the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\def\end@rotdblfloat{%
  \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \stepcounter{r@tfl@t}%
  \rot@label{RF\ther@tfl@t}%
  \rot@pageref{RF\ther@tfl@t}{\R@@page}%
  \edef\@tempa{Adding sideways \@captype\space on page \R@@page\space}
  \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\@tempa}
  \@tempdima\ht\rot@float@box
  \advance\@tempdima by \dp\rot@float@box
  \wd\rot@float@box\z@
  \ht\rot@float@box\z@
  \dp\rot@float@box\z@
  \vbox to \textheight{%
    \setkeys{Grot}{units=360}%
    \if@rot@twoside
    \else
      \let\R@@page\rot@LR
    \fi
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\R@@page}}{%
      \ifrot@messages
        \if@rot@twoside
  \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\the\rot@mess@toks (right hand page)}%
\fi
      \fi
      \vfill
      \@@line{%
        \hskip\rotFPtop
        \rotatebox{-90}{\box\rot@float@box}%
        \hskip\rotFPbot
      }%
    }{%
      \ifrot@messages
        \if@rot@twoside
  \rot@mess@toks\expandafter{\the\rot@mess@toks (left hand page)}%
\fi
      \fi%
      \@@line{%
        \hskip\rotFPbot
        \rotatebox{90}{\box\rot@float@box}%
        \hskip\rotFPtop
      }%
      \vfill
    }%
    \rot@message{\the\rot@mess@toks}%
  }%
  \end@dblfloat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

I have copied the relevant part of `rotating.sty` and changed the direction of the rotation by replacing `\rotatebox{-90}` by `\rotatebox{90}` and vice versa.