# On the proper orientation of sideway figures in book documentclass

Tags: rotating, double-sided, bookmarks, layout, sidewaysfigure

Consider the following mwe

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
  \caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image]

The text margins here perfectly fine with larger margins on the outside and odd pages on the right. The problem I have is with the `sidewaysfigure`. In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93941) answer @torbjørn-t correctly points out that "*the caption is always rotated toward the outer edge of the page*" (however, in that question there we have even page on the right). Which is not clearly the case here. It seems to me the way is depicted here, is not very comfortable to read in contrast to an image rotate towards the outside but I might be wrong here.

I know I can rotate it manually but I want to know if the image above is wrong in the first place or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a book (twosided) where the lefthand page has a sideways figure, as does the righthand page. These figures must be rotated in the same direction as otherwise to read them one will have to turn the book first one way then the other.

Personally I prefer figures to be rotated to the left, as in your example, with the caption underneath (which is the usual location of a figure's caption). Then with the above scenario I rotate the book to the right (verso page is on top) and read top to bottom; if it is all the other way round then the recto page is on the top and everything looks topsy-turvy to me.

Whatever scheme you choose, be consistent.

EDIT I have looked at my 6 books on typography and book design and in only one instance are sideways illustrations commented on: Ruari McLean, *The Thames and Hudson Manual of Typography*, 1980, where he says "Turned illustrations are almost as annoying as finding a page of text printed upside down". I guess that this in effect means that there is probably no generally accepted typographical convention (apart from "don't do it"). However in all cases the authors when talking about illustrations were meaning things like photographs or paintings not diagrams or tables.

But it is a typographical convention, unless you are into avant-garde design, to be consistent in what you do.

With the `rotating` package you can ensure that sideways stuff is rotated consistently by specifying the `figuresright` or `figuresleft` package option.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and writing this. Unfortunately however, this doesn't really address my problem. I'm interested in two goals: 1) to understand the correct layout design and 2) to avoid tailoring and manually forcing a particular behavior. I could indeed ensure that all are rotated one way or another but this is very error prone and could introduce inconsistencies that you pointed out correctly. Moreover, rotating package actually put the figure 180 degree rotated if appear on even pages [...]

Comment: [...] Finally, I *personally* find it more comfortable to have it rotate the other way around comparing to what is shown above. That is to raise my left/right hand when to figure appear on the left/right. Note that I'm not saying I'm right or you are wrong. I'm merely pointing out that there should be a standard convention which I like to follow instead of personal preference. This is the whole point of my question. Please note that this is not an attack, I genuinely would like to know the typographical rule here. Again I appreciate the answer, Cheers!

Comment: @Pouya I have extended my answer to meet your comments.

Comment: thank you for insightful edit. *"Turned illustrations are almost as annoying as finding a page of text printed upside down"*. Ouch! I think I learned my lesson here!. I happily accept the answer :)